# Subversion Pre Commit / Latest Version Check

Tags: svn

I'd like to be able to set my subversion project to force developers to update to the latest version of the code before they can commit.

Although Subversion will by default do this if the same file is edited, I want it to check my local copy revision (say 7000) against the server head revision (say 7001) and reject the commit until the local copy has been updated.

We use Tortoise SVN if that helps at all.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: What's the objective Michael? Like you say, SVN won't let you commit before an update if the file in the repository is newer anyway. There are some very valid reasons why developer's might not want to update before a commit (i.e. different devs working in discrete modules of the same codebase).